# get_users meta_query

Tags: meta-query, users

I can't get meta_queries working correctly on get_users(). For the life of me can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
    $args = array(
        'meta_query'   =>

            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',

            array(
                'key' => 'minbeds',
                'value' => $rooms,
                'compare' => "<=",
                'type' => 'numeric'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'maxbeds',
                'value' =>  $rooms,
                'compare' => "=>",
                'type' => 'numeric'
            )
           array(
                'key' => 'minprice',
                'value' => $price,
                'compare' => "<=",
                'type' => 'numeric'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'maxprice',
                'value' => $price,
                'compare' => "=>",
                'type' => 'numeric'
            )
         )
    );

    $users = get_users( $args );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`meta_query` parameter is an array of arrays,

```
    $args = array(
        'meta_query'=>

         array(

            array(

                'relation' => 'AND',

            array(
                'key' => 'minbeds',
                'value' => $rooms,
                'compare' => "<=",
                'type' => 'numeric'
            ),

            array(
                'key' => 'maxbeds',
                'value' =>  $rooms,
                'compare' => ">=",
                'type' => 'numeric'
            ),

           array(
                'key' => 'minprice',
                'value' => $price,
                'compare' => "<=",
                'type' => 'numeric'
            ),

            array(
                'key' => 'maxprice',
                'value' => $price,
                'compare' => ">=",
                'type' => 'numeric'
            )
          )
       )
    );

    $users = get_users( $args );
```

Comment: Shouldn't "relation" be outside of that array? Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think `"relation" => "AND"` should be in the first dimension of the array.